# Why doesn't my microphone work?

Tags: windows-7, microphone

When I talk into my microphone while there are no programs using it I can hear myself in the headphones. When I try to record myself using a program it doesn't record any audio. I am using Windows 7 and a Cosonic headset. It works on my brother's PC but not on mine, I can't seem to any mic response from my PC. The program doesn't require to locate the input device. I'm trying to use it on MSN & the website Livemocha.com

Comment: does the program require you to select the input source? and if so, have you?

Comment: What program and OS are you using? It's hard to pinpoint an issue when we don't have any information...

Comment: Livemocha.com uses Flash. You may want to add that bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

For flash microphone configuration check here: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html